# Decoding Factorio blueprints in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell

In the game Factorio there are string-encoded representations of blueprints that I wish to decode.

The implementation according to their wiki is the following:

> This is a technical description of the blueprint string format, used to share blueprints with other users.
>
> A blueprint string is a json representation of the blueprint, encoded using base 64 with the version byte in front (0 in vanilla 0.15) and then compressed with zlib deflate. So to get the json representation of a blueprint from a blueprint string, skip the first byte, base64 decode the string, and finally decompress using zlib deflate.

Please keep in mind that I am very new to Haskell, having only played around with it maybe once earlier in my life, though I do have some functional programming experience.

The list of dependencies is the following:

- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- bytestring
- base64-bytestring
- zlib

The `Main.hs` file:

```
module Main where

import Lib
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    if null args
        then putStrLn "Usage: factorio-exe <blueprint-string>"
        else putStrLn (blueprintJson (head args))
```

The `Lib.hs` file:

```
module Lib
    ( blueprintJson
    ) where

import Codec.Compression.Zlib
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L
import Data.ByteString.Base64

blueprintJson :: [Char] -> [Char]
blueprintJson str = bpDeflate (bpDecode str)

bpDecode :: [Char] -> C.ByteString
bpDecode str = let (Right decoded) = decode (C.pack (tail str)) in decoded

bpDeflate :: C.ByteString -> [Char]
bpDeflate bstr = L.unpack (decompress (L.fromStrict bstr))
```

An example blueprint string to test with is the following:

> 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

Do note that when decoding that there may appear characters with which the Windows Command Prompt may have issues displaying.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's not much to say, to be honest. The type signatures are all there, which is a plus.

## Communicate possible errors and make functions total

However, `bpDecode` has two possible runtime error sources: `tail` (which is partial) and `Right _ = decode`, since the latter can return a `Left`. Therefore `bpDecode` is partial too. In Haskell, we try to keep the partial functions to a minimum. `bpDecode` can fail, but it's type does not communicate that to us.

Instead, `bpDecode` should return `Either String C.ByteString` as `decode`. We can use `String` to communicate another possible error, namely an empty `String`:

```
bpDecode :: [Char] -> Either String C.ByteString
bpDecode "" = Left "bpDecode: Empty String"
bpDecode s  = decode . C.pack . tail $ s
```

Alternatively, if you don't care about empty string case, we can use `drop 1` instead of `tail`. The former always returns a list, even if our original list was empty:

```
bpDecode :: [Char] -> Either String C.ByteString
bpDecode = decode . C.pack . drop 1
```

Some libraries provide a "I know it's correct" function and you can too:

```
bpDecode' :: [Char] -> C.ByteString
bpDecode' s = let (Right d) = bpDecode s in d
```

but that's an aside. However, now `bpDecode` is total: for any input it will produce an output.

## Use `hlint` to find possible eta-reductions

While not necessary, this could be a good time to learn about `hlint`. It will report common improvements on your code. In this case, you can write `bpDeflate` as

```
bpDeflate :: C.ByteString -> [Char]
bpDeflate = L.unpack . decompress . L.fromStrict
```

and `blueprintJson` as

```
blueprintJson :: [Char] -> [Char]
blueprintJson = bpDeflate . bpDecode
```

## Try to stay in a single character stream type

Haskell has 5 types that work with strings. `ByteString` (lazy and strict), `Text` (lazy and strict) and `String` (aka `[Char]`). If possible try to stick to one of them and don't switch between them all the time. For example, all your functions can be written with lazy `ByteString`s:

```
import Codec.Compression.Zlib
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L
import Data.ByteString.Base64.Lazy

blueprintJson :: L.ByteString -> Either String L.ByteString
blueprintJson = fmap bpDeflate . bpDecode

bpDecode :: L.ByteString -> Either String L.ByteString
bpDecode = decode . L.drop 1

bpDeflate :: L.ByteString -> L.ByteString
bpDeflate = decompress
```

Note that I changed `blueprintJson`'s type, since we also changed `bpDecode`'s type. In case you're not familiar with `fmap`: in this context you can think of `fmap` as

```
fmap f (Right r) = Right (f r)
fmap _ (Left  l) = Left l
```

Regardless, the string type depends of course on your later use case. Since `blueprintJson` hints that you will decode JSON, you will likely use [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) later, which uses **lazy** `ByteString`s as well.

Given those functions above, we could now write `blueprintJson` as

```
blueprintJson :: L.ByteString -> Either String L.ByteString
blueprintJson = fmap decompress . decode . L.drop 1

blueprintJson' :: L.ByteString -> L.ByteString
blueprintJson' = fromRight . blueprintJson

fromRight :: Either a b -> b
fromRight e = -- left as an exercise
```

## Prefer pattern matches instead of boolean guards

In `main`, you check whether the list is `null`. That still enables us to accide

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    if null args
        then putStrLn (blueprintJson (head args)) -- woops!
        else putStrLn "Usage: factorio-exe <blueprint-string>"
```

If you pattern match you cannot accidentally use `head` on an empty list:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
      [b] -> putStrLn (blueprintJson b) 
      _   -> putStrLn "Usage: factorio-exe <blueprint-string>"
```

Comment: How would using a lazy ByteString work for the decode function? On https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Base64.html it states that it uses the strict variant, so I don't see how it could work.

Comment: @skiwi there's a lazy variant, too: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Base64-Lazy.html. I accidentally forgot to change the import.